# How to read JSON error message React-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Wandering into uncharted waters, I've been having some trouble figuring out how to access an error message I made in my Rails API thru my React Frontend. I've been reading through a good amount of sites and so far I haven't really been able to figure out where i'm going wrong. Is it on the Rails side or the React side?

**TLDR;** I want my response error to be: "Username or Password does not match.", but I am getting: "Request failed with status code 422"

**Rails Controller**

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params["user"]["email"]).try(:authenticate, params["user"]["password"])

    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      render json: {
        status: 200,
        logged_in: true,
        user: user
      }
    else
      // how can I reach this error message?
      render json: { status: "error", message: "Username or Password does not match." }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

...
```

**React Component**

```
handleLogin = (e) => {      
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
        .post(
            'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/sessions',
            {
                user: { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password }
            },
            { withCredentials: true }
        )
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.logged_in) {
                this.handleSuccessfulAuth(response.data);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // returns login error Request failed with status code 422
            console.log('login error', error.message);
        });
};
```

Comment: Any luck on getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your message property could be accessible like this:

```
.catch(error => { 
           console.log('login error', error.response.data.message);
      });
```